# Unknown provider error in AngularJS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

Now I am working on a project using Asp.Net MVC + AngularJS. Everything go well in development, but when I run it on IIS, an error occurs:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: nProvider <- n
```

How can I locate the `nProvider`? How can I fix this error?

Screenshots of my errors:

[image: Console output]

[image: Javascript source]

Comment: Post your code where the problem occurs

Comment: sounds like  a minification problem. Look for `n` in the injections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try reading the answer to this post and see if it helps you.

You should be able to see the component's name in the function hopefully. a bit poor but better than nothing. let's hope angular 2.0 is a little more helpful.

[Finding the cause of "Unknown provider" errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22197191/finding-the-cause-of-unknown-provider-errors)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks above all. It's really a minification problem. I'v found the solution, please refer the following codes, the italic codes are added to fix the problem.

Change

```
var app = angular.module('app', [
    'ui.router',
    '...'
])
.run(function ($templateCache, $http) {
    $http.get('tpl.path')
        .then(function(response) {
            // ...
        });
});
```

To

```
var app = angular.module('app', [
    'ui.router',
    '...'
])
.run(['$templateCache', '$http', function ($templateCache, $http) {
    $http.get('tpl.path')
        .then(function(response) {
            // ...
        });
}]);
```