# Heroku Unknown Provider

Tags: node.js, angularjs, heroku, provider

Good morning,

I'm trying to deploy a sample angularjs project on Heroku but I get this error:

Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: aProvider <- a

This is my Gruntfile.js:

```
grunt.registerTask('heroku:production', [
'clean:dist','wiredep','useminPrepare','concurrent:dist','autoprefixer','concat','ngmin',
'copy:dist','cdnify', 'cssmin','uglify', 'filerev', 'usemin:dist']);
```

All my controllers, services and providers are rewritten using this syntax:

```
var dett = angular.module('DettRipetizioniCtrlModule', []);

dett.controller('DettRipetizioniCtrl', [ '$scope', '$routeParams', '$location', 'services', function ($scope, $routeParams, $location, services) {
//do stuff
}
```

and my app.js file is:

```
var app = angular.module('lemieripetizioni3App',['ngRoute','ngAnimate','Services','DettRipetizioniCtrlModule','Animations','RicercaRipetizioniCtrlModule']);
```

This is my git repo: https://github.com/gterribilio/lmr.git

Any ideas? Could be a minification problem on Heroku? Using the same grunttask on localhost works fine.

Thanks in advance.

Giuseppe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a minification issue, as you mentioned, and a really annoying one...

This post goes into great detail into the debugging part of the problem, it saved my life twice already :-)

["Unknown provider: aProvider <- a" How do I find the original provider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21688681/unknown-provider-aprovider-a-how-do-i-find-the-original-provider)

Comment: Thanks for your reply!

After many headaches I found the solution!

I had in my app.js file 

    .run(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.userData = {};
    sessionStorage.isLogged=false;
    });

this piece of code in which I declared globally variables and Heroku didn't like it.

Thanks for you help!

Giuseppe